# Ensuring referential integrity between Columns in a Table

Tags: database, referential-integrity

Currently I have a table model with the following format:

**criteria (criteria_id, criteria_name)**

**criteria_data(criteria_id, value)**

I intend on storing Date-related information into the table in the sense that one criteria ( the Date criteria) could just contain the single date in the criteria_data table while other criteria_data could be the price of the stock for the date in a separate row. ( Another complication is that: the name of the stock is also a criteria)

My problem:

How is it possible for me to ensure that only 1 price ( single row criteria) can be entered into the table for a particular date and stock name ( 2 other separate criteria and rows).

I really don't want to enforce this in the App layer so I am mainly looking for DB Layer solutions , if available.

I am also open to being told to scrap my entire table model, if a more suitable Data model is suggested.

**EDIT**
After being informed of my folly ( see dPortas post below), I accept that this is not the smart way to go. I thought of a new model:

**criteria_data(stockName,price, high,low,price,change)**

While this is what it looks like, I am thinking the actual column names would be an identifier containing the criteria_id . For example, the stockname field could be col_1 and high could be col_3 but this would ensure that I could enforce integrity on the various columns.

What are people thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table design looks suspiciously like a case of [EAV](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html). Among the disadvantages of that anti-pattern are that you can't accurately store the right datatypes or apply constraints to it. I suggest you reconsider the design.

Suggested redesign: criteria (criteria_id, criteria_name, date, stock_name, price) key: (stock_name, date)

Comment: That silly EAV thing is exactly what I am trying to achieve but your design **MAY** not work for me precisely because I was looking for an effecient way to reference different fields such as the High price, low price and current price using separate field. I have edited my post to reflect your brilliant observation